# Epllisis not working in IE

Tags: css

I have a table and in th i have added inline css for showing dot if text is bigger.Its working fine in other browser except in IE9

Below is my code

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed hardware-software-table">
                            <tbody><tr style="background-color: #8A8A8D; color: #fff;">
                                <th style="width: calc(100% - 10px);overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">VendorName</th>
                                <th style="width: calc(100% - 200px);overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">Account No</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>

                        </tbody></table>
```

Please see the screenshot too[image]

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question.  It is really a question about how to use a tool - Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some changes in you html. for better performance you can use span tag inside th and it will work fine and define the width of span tag.

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed hardware-software-table">
                            <tbody><tr style="background-color: #8A8A8D; color: #fff;">
                                <th><span style="width: 100px;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; display:block;"">VendorName aASDASDASD</span></th>
                                <th ><span style="width: 100px;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; display:block;"">Account Number</span></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>

                        </tbody></table>
```